# how i can call this class?

Tags: python, function, class, average

```
class average :
        def myinput():
                n=0
                mylist=[]
                #will be ended when input = -1 
                while n !='-1' :
                    n=raw_input('>>>')
                    if n!='-1' :
                        mylist.append(n)
                print lol(mylist)
        def lol(mylist):
               try: 
                mysum=0.0
                for i in mylist :
                    mysum=mysum+int(i)
                return mysum/len(mylist)
               except:
                  return  'please don\'t Enter charecters just Number' 
ave=average
ave.myinput()
```

what is the wrong with this code ?

> $ winpty python test3.py Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test3.py", line 20, in 
>       ave.myinput() TypeError: unbound method myinput() must be called with
>   average instance as firs t argument (got nothing instead)"""

Comment: python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should rename your class, Python naming convention are really strong and class should always start with a capital letter.

Then to answer: You simply forgot the ()

```
ave = Average()
ave.myinput()
```

And you should put the class instance in each method:

`def myinput(self): ...`

`def lol(self, mylist):`

Comment: class Average :
       
ave=Average()
ave.myinput()


"""$ winpty python test3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 20, in <module>
    ave.myinput()
TypeError: myinput() takes no arguments (1 given)

"""
i change class name and i put the ()

Comment: Weird, it's working on my machine, did you refreshed your `ave` object ? If you update the class you'll need to recreate it either way it will stay the same as before

Answer (score 1):

Your class should be like this:

```
class Average() :
    def myinput(self):
        n=0
        mylist=[]
        #will be ended when input = -1 
        while n !='-1' :
            n=raw_input('>>>')
            if n!='-1' :
                mylist.append(n)
        print self.lol(mylist)
    def lol(self, mylist):
        try: 
            mysum=0.0
            for i in mylist :
                mysum = mysum + int(i)
            return mysum/len(mylist)
        except:
            return  'please don\'t Enter charecters just Number' 
ave = Average()
ave.myinput()
```

This first argument should be class instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

You missed brackets here.

```
ave=average()
```

Comment: ave=average()  
ave.myinput()  


"""$ winpty python test3.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "test3.py", line 20, in <module>  
    ave.myinput()  
TypeError: myinput() takes no arguments (1 given)  
 
"""

Comment: your functions are missing the `self` parameter. You need to declare it as `def myinput(self):`